# Weird issue debugging LogicalBinaryExpression vs BinaryExpression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

Long story short, I've got a method where I'm taking an `Expression` as an argument, and the argument is a `Linq` expression.

The problem is that when debugging from VS, the expression's `GetType().Name` returns `BinaryExpression` and everything is fine. But in the deployed version of the application (still deployed onto my dev machine,) that same call return `LogicalBinaryExpression` instead and it causes issues down the road.

Is there a specific dll or something that needs updated/changed? Does anyone know why the behavior would change even though its the same machine and the same dll's?

Comment: How are you creating the expression?  And what are you trying to do with it?  You likely shouldn't be using the type name like this in the first place.

Comment: Sounds like the debugging libraries are different.  Why is this a problem for you?

Comment: Have you considered using the `ExpressionType` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361179.aspx) rather than the name of the type of an instance when analyzing the expressions? It's much more likely to be consistent across different scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that in VS, the app pool framework was set to 2.0 while my actual IIS app pool for the app was set to 4.0.

Found out by setting a breakpoint and calling `GetType().Assembly` in the immediate window when debugging in both environments. They returned different versions of the same dll in the GAC.